# JQuery find and replace text with button and ignore what is there on subsequent clicks

Tags: jquery

When the user selects the find and replace button, I have it replacing the text with a button and span inside.  That all works fine. If they select the find and replace button again, the find/replace script should not change the exising button/span combo. How can I not overwrite that button with the span on subsequent selection of the find and replace button for the same keyword and tag?

This is what I have tried...

```
<div class="select--highlight--active">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry standard dummy.</div>

Tag Name:
<p>
    <input class="form-control tag_name" value="1" />
</p>

Find & Replace
<p>
    <input class="form-control the_keyword" value="dummy" />
</p>

$(document).on('click', ".btn_find_replace", function (e) {

            var the_keyword =  $(".the_keyword").val().trim();
            var tag = $(".tag_name").val().trim();
            var re = new RegExp('[^<\\/](' + the_keyword + ')', 'g');

            $(".select--highlight--active").each(function () {
                if ($(this).not(this).find("button,span")) {
                    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace( re, "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs ner_tag' data-unique-name data-start='" + tag + "'>" + the_keyword + " <span class='badge margin_left' data-unique-name>" + tag + "</span></button>" ) );
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of jQuery's [`.one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/).

Once you clicked the button "find and replace", it unbinds the click handler.

So in your case it would look something like this:

```
$(".btn_find_replace").one('click', function (e) {

  var the_keyword =  $(".the_keyword").val().trim();
  var tag = $(".tag_name").val().trim();
  var re = new RegExp('[^<\\/](' + the_keyword + ')', 'g');

  $(".select--highlight--active").each(function () {
    if ($(this).not(this).find("button,span")) {
      $(this).html( $(this).html().replace( re, "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs ner_tag' data-unique-name data-start='" + tag + "'>" + the_keyword + " <span class='badge margin_left' data-unique-name>" + tag + "</span></button>" ) );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: its the button/span that should not be duplicated, not the click/event.  when you click it now an errant span tag shows up, basically the html is mungled.

Comment: @Rob Well, if the click event doesn't execute twice, the button won't replace twice. And since that's the only thing that gets done in the click function, it does the job, I'd say. Or do I get something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.  Added another data attribute so I could find and replace that button via the same keyword if it is used.  Basically an auto remove and then replace.

```
//auto remove all buttons with the same tag name
$('.select--highlight--active').each(function(i,v) {

    if ($(this).find('.ner_tag[data-keyword="' + the_keyword + '"]').length !==0){
         $(this).find('.ner_tag[data-keyword="' + the_keyword + '"]').replaceWith(" " + the_keyword);
    }

    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace( re, "<button class='btn btn-sm ner_tag' style='background:" + stringToColour(tag, 66) + "'  data-unique-name data-start='" + tag + "' data-keyword='" + the_keyword + "' >" + the_keyword + " <span class='badge margin_left' style='background:" + stringToColour(tag,"") + "' data-unique-name>" + tag + "</span></button>" ) );

});
```